# How to get probability of $X \le Y + Z$ for $X, Y, Z$ all from the same specific distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, convolution

I'm struggling to get the probability of $\mathbb{P}[X\le Y+Z]$ where all three are from the same distribution with the following pdf:

$$f_X (x) = \frac{2(x-a)}{(b-a)^2}$$
where $0<a<b$.  (Notice the pdf above comes from taking the maximum of two random variables uniformly distributed between $a,b$).

However, I know that I need to use convolution to compute $\mathbb{P}[X\le Y+Z]$ where $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d.  But I admit that I'm stuck on this convolution step.  How do I convolve these and get $\mathbb{P}[X\le Y+Z]$?

Comment: Did you try to compute the convolution integral? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition

Comment: I tried convolving the function with itself using wolfram alpha but I couldn't get any understandable output.  It introduces another variable called the "transform variable" which I don't understand.  The output of a convolution  of a function of a single variable should just be a function of the single variable.

Comment: You cannot find it with the given information. Do you know the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$? Convolution can only be used if you know that the variables are **independent**.

Comment: yes they are IID.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that is conceptually easy, but computationally messy, and best solved with the help of a computer algebra system. As you have noted, the solution must obviously be a function of parameters $a$ and $b$.

Given that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables, their joint pdf $f(x,y,z)$ is simply the product of the individual pdf's:

[image]

We seek $P(X < Y+Z)$:

[image]

where I am using the `Prob` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*, where as full disclosure, I note that I am one of the authors. All done.

Note that this probability is always close to 1. Here is a plot of the probability, with arbitrarily $a = 1$, as $b$ increases:

[image]

It appears the smallest the probability can be is $\frac{17}{18}$:

[image]

Comment: That's great, but I'd like to understand the fundamentals.  When I convolve $\frac{2(x-a)}{(b-a)^2}$ with itself, I'm getting $\frac{-2*(4a+2b-3x}{3(a-b)^2}$.  This is a pdf and should integrate to 1 over the limits $(a,b)$ (it integrates to 4/3 or something).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since my above comment seems like a separate question, I separated it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726611/. Thanks for your continued attention to helping me.

Comment: Is $2a \ge b$ the only condition?  I'm trying to connect this to the other answers from @ThomasAhle and check their consistency.  If you could share your wolfram notebook (if you have one available), i'd be very much obliged.  I'm trying to get this working myself.  Thanks again

Comment: All the 'workings' are already shown - the above input is self-contained. And the conditional output is also fully shown:  it reads IF $2 a >b$, then the probability is 1; otherwise the expression shown.

Comment: The package `Prob` doesn't seem available in wolframcloud.  Is it only available on local mathematica?

Comment: As stated in the answer, `Prob` is a function that is part of _mathStatica_, which is an add-on package for _Mathematica_. Unfortunately, this is not available as part of Wolframcloud. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Updated the answer to the new question.

To expand on my answer in the comments, you can check my Mathematica notebook here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/d4a194bf-fb09-4ce3-abe6-4238d62e53e0

If $$p(x) = \frac{2(x-a)}{(a-b)^2} * \mathbb1[a<x<b]$$

You get the convolution (and pdf for the sum)
$$
q(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)p(y-x)dx
= 
\begin{cases} -\frac{2 (2 a-y)^3}{3 (a-b)^4)} & a<b, 2 a<y, a+b\ge y\\
\frac{2 (2 b-y) (6 a^2-2 b^2-6 a y+2 b y+y^2)}{3 (a-b)^4} & a<b, a+b<y, 2 b>y.
\end{cases}
$$
Just using the formula from the [Wikipedia page says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition).
The only difficulty is getting all the cases of the integration right, but Mathematica helps with that.

Comment: the factor of 2 was not a mistake, however I did forget to square the denominator - see editted question above.  I'm trying to edit your notebook with the pdf in the updated question, but if you're able to do it faster, please update the link.

Comment: Also - your answer is not a function of $a,b$.  Why not?

Comment: @somewhere I've updated it to your new question now. But please don't change your question that much after you've asked it. I ended up getting downvotes because my answer no longer matched your question, even though I spent a lot of time trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that.  Yes, I understand that now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I created a copy of your notebook, and I'm trying to get the final results $\mathbb{P}[X \le Y+Z]$.  I'm not that familiar with mathematica, but I tried to get the final result using your notebook by `Probability[p[x_,a_,b_] < conv]` (based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255821/)), but I'm not able to specify the distribution correctly using this.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X \leq Y+Z)  = \int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b F(y+z) f(y) f(z) \ dy \ dz$$

$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(y) dy = \int_a^x \frac{2(y-a)}{(b-a)^2} dy = \frac{2(\frac{x^2-a^2}{2} - a(x-a))}{(b-a)^2} = \frac{(x-a)^2}{(b-a)^2}$$

Now $$P(X \leq Y+Z)  = \int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b F(y+z) f(y) f(z)$$

is an integration of polynomials in $y,z$. Try to take it from here on.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the very first expression.  More specifically, how did you avoid convolution?

Comment: $\int P(X\leq Y+Z |y,z) P(y) P(z) dy dz =\int P(X \leq y+z) P(y) P(z) \ dy \ dz=\int F(y+z) f(y) f(z) \ dy \ dz$