# How to determine integration limits for convolution of piecewise function with itself?

Tags: probability, convolution

I have the cdf of the *maximum* of two iid uniformly distributed random variables $x,y \sim U[a,b]$ (if that's incorrect, please let me know why).  $X = \max (x,y)$ :

$$ F_X(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x \ge b \\
      (\frac{x-a}{b-a})^2 & x \in (a,b) \\
      0 & x \le a \\
   \end{cases}
$$

Now, I determine the pdf by taking the derivative:

$$ f_X(x)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x \ge b \\
      \frac{2(x-a)}{(b-a)^2} & x \in (a,b) \\
      0 & x \le a \\
   \end{cases}
$$

Now I'd like to get the pdf of $X_1 + X_2$. $X_1, X_2 = \max (x,y) $.  So I do convolution:

$$f_{X_1 + X_2}(t)=\int_{2a}^{2b} f(x)*f(t-x) dx = \int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{2(x-a)}{(b-a)^2} \frac{2(((t-x)-a)}{(b-a)^2} dx = \frac{(8 ((a + 2 b)^2 - 3 b t))}{(3 (a - b)^3)}$$

The above result does not integrate to $1$.
$$\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{(8 ((a + 2 b)^2 - 3 b t))}{(3 (a - b)^3)} dt \ne 1$$
So, I must have done something incorrect here.  What's wrong about this?

I have a feeling something is wrong with my integration limits in one of the above integrals.  Is that what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: And $X_1,X_2$ are..?

Comment: There are many unclear things. First of all you didn't said what $X_1,X_2$ are but I assume you mean the two uniformly distributed random variables, you didn't said that they are independent but most importantly if by $X_1,X_2$ you mean the two uniformly distributed random variables then $f * f$ is not the pdf of $X_1 + X_2$. In any case the computation is wrong because $t-x$ may not lie in $[a,b]$, if you take this into account you need to integrate not on $[a,b]$ but on $[max(a,t-b) , min(b , t - a)]$

Comment: You are assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _independent_ random variables with the given pdf.  $X_1+X_2$ takes on values in $[2a,2b]$ and the convolution is _not_ what you write it to be.

Comment: Right, that was my suspicion too initially.  But even when I fix the convolution to be between $2a, 2b$, the output of the convolution doesn't integrate to 1. $\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{(8 ((a + 2 b)^2 - 3 b t))}{(3 (a - b)^3)} \ne 1$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include this in the comment above: $\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{2(x-a)}{(b-a)^2} \frac{2(((t-x)-a)}{(b-a)^2} dx = \frac{(8 ((a + 2 b)^2 - 3 b t))}{(3 (a - b)^3)}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Does the question make sense now?  I editted it, and also my comments above should explain my problem.  THanks.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ is nonzero only when $x \in [a,b]$ and so the _integrand_ $f(x)f(t-x)$ has value $0\cdot f(t-x) = 0$ when $x \in [2a,2b]$. Thus, the integral has value $0$, and not what you write. Perhaps drawing a sketch of the support of the joint pdf and marking on it the line $x_1+x_2 = t$ will help you figure out the convolution.

Comment: Ah, I'm starting to see your point Thanks! (and thanks to @Paul whom I think is saying the same thing).  However, integrating over the limits $\max (a, t-b), \min (b, t-a)$ makes it difficult to actually compute. (I know $0<a<b$, but that's it. 

How do I know the minimum/maximum beforehand?  I tried computing using the limits $t-a,t-b$, but my sanity check of seeing if integrating the output equals 1, still fails :(

Comment: @somewhere just distinguish cases $t < a + b$ , $t \geq a + b$

Comment: @Paul, thanks. Right, got that. Using limits $(a, t-a)$ seems correct, and the output of convolution integral is $\frac{(-2 (2 a - t)^3)}{(3 (a - b)^4)}$   However, the sanity check still fails when I integrate this result from $t=2a,t=2b$.